# Resize image client side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to resize images from an input field.

Currently I am getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

And I'm not really sure how everything is done. Do I just resize the file and then proceed with the form process?

The code:

```
    $( "input#item-images" ).change(function() {
        var file = this.files;

        jQuery.each( file, function( i, val ) {
            alert(i + val['name']);

            var file = val['name'];

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {img.src = e.target.result}
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        });

        console.log(file);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the name property of the File object to the `file` variable when you're doing `var file = val['name'];`, and then passing the name to `readAsArrayBuffer` in `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);`.

To fix this, you could replace this code:

```
    var file = this.files;

    jQuery.each( file, function( i, val ) {
        alert(i + val['name']);

        var file = val['name'];
```

With this:

```
    jQuery.each( this.files, function( i, file ) {
        alert(i + file['name']);
```

However, when you fix this issue, the next issue pops up, which is that `canvas` is undefined. I don't know if you expect the rest of the code to work, maybe you defined canvas somewhere else.